# Adding length-contraction tag won't work

Tags: support, tags, editing, tag-synonyms

I recently asked [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/558154/) question. Before posting, I added the tags [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) and [length-contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/length-contraction), but after posting, only the [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) tag remained. I tried multiple times to edit in the [length-contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/length-contraction) tag, but it wouldn't work.

I then tried adding the [time-dilation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-dilation) tag, and it worked perfectly. It seems that this bug is only happening for the [length-contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/length-contraction) tag.

Comment: Just to make something explicit that QMechanic implies in their [answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12958/179151), this isn't a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the [length-contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/length-contraction) tag was made a synonym of the [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) tag in 2014. FYI, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/special-relativity/synonyms) is a list of the current synonyms of the [special-relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-relativity) tag.

Comment: Well that makes sense. I would have thought that time-dialation would fall in the same category though. It would be helpful if there was some indication of synonyms when adding tags. Thanks for the answer.